# AWS CDK Bootstrap itself broken

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

A few months ago I played around with AWS CDK and so I of course did the `cdk bootstrap`.

At that time I stopped playing around and thought I'd never use it again. Having a kind of neatly attitude in this kind of things (and missing an undo or delete option being delivered with the cdk itself :/ ) I deleted all cdk objects from my account.

Or at least I thought so, because now (starting to play around again), calling `cdk bootstrap` does "nothing":

✅  *Environment aws://xxxxxxxxx/eu-central-1 bootstrapped (no changes).*

But trying to `cdk deploy` gives me:

`fail: No bucket named 'cdk-XXXXXXXXXXX-eu-central-1'. Is account XXXXXXXXXXXX bootstrapped?`

Well yes right...I don't have any buckets at all at the moment.

Is there a way to `cdk bootstrap --force` that I'am missing? Is there a list of all objects I should have deleted? I find a lot suggestions for people having problems with their stacks, but I have no idea how to fix this.

*Edit*: I just "solved" the problem, by creating a bucket with the given cryptic name...but that doesn't feel right. So I leave this Question open, to see if there is a better way to do it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Bootstrapping](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/cli.html#cli-bootstrap) creates a Stack called `CDKToolkit`, which has the CloudFormation resources CDK needs to deploy.  You can safely "uninstall-reinstall" it:

```sh
aws cloudformation delete-stack --stack-name CDKToolkit

cdk bootstrap
```

Note:  "Drift" is the technical term for your problem.  The actual AWS resource state "drifted" from the expected state defined in the `CDKToolkit` CloudFormation template.  CloudFormation has [tools to deal with the drift problem](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-cfn-stack-drift.html). You can report on drift, for instance:

```sh
aws cloudformation detect-stack-drift --stack-name CDKToolkit
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I didn't realize the `CDKToolkit` the first time I created it. It is not even mentionend in your link. But 1. Delete the Bucket again, 2. call `aws cloudformation delete ...` 3. Bootstrapping again did it :)

Comment: I had a similar issue, the stack was partially deleted, when I ran `aws cloudformation delete-stack...` it did not delete the IAM roles since I do not have permission to delete them.   This left the stack in a DELETE FAILED state, where `cdk bootstrap` could not recover.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps future googlers:

```bash
cdk bootstrap --trust=$ACCOUNT_ID \
  --cloudformation-execution-policies arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AdministratorAccess \
  aws://$ACCOUNT_ID/us-west-2 \
  aws://$ACCOUNT_ID/us-east-2 \
  aws://$ACCOUNT_ID/us-east-1
```

I ran the above as part of the [eks-blueprints-cdk-workshop, (the self paced one)](https://catalog.workshops.aws/eks-blueprints-for-cdk/en-US/020-setup/self-paced), and had a ton of trouble with it, because deleting the s3 bucket & CloudFormat Stack wasn't correctly resetting the initial state.

By trouble I mean it'd bootstrap 2 of 3 regions, and then say the 3rd had already been bootstrapped which I knew had to be incorrect since this was my 1st time doing the lab. I then followed the accepted answer to try to fix it, but upon retrying it said only 1 of 3 regions would bootstrap.

That's when I remembered that:
**CloudFormation stacks are a regional resource. So if you still have trouble getting back to a fresh state after following the above, double-check your regions / that you don't have CDKToolkit deployed to multiple regions and that you're removing it from the correct region / all relevant regions.**

(I now realize that the cause of this was me forgetting to fully and completely clean up my environment after following a different how to guide.)

Once I deleted the `CDKToolkit` CF Stack from the 3 regions mentioned in the above command, and then re-ran the above cdk bootstrap command it finally worked as expected. Makes perfect sense in retrospect, but it didn't immediately occur to me that CF stacks are regional resources, since I tend to stay away from CF stacks in general in favor of higher level abstractions.